# Purpose of Carrier Detect (CD) pin in RF modules

Tags: rf, high-frequency

I have a RX2-433-160-3V receiver module from Radiometrix. I wanted to know what the purpose of the CD pin is. I have read the datasheet but don't really understand what it's meant to do. The datasheet just talks about external circuits that you can connect to the CD pin.

It did mention this: "A fast-acting carrier detect and a power-up enable time of less than
1ms. This allows effective duty cycle power saving and a -107 dBm sensitivity."

Does it have to do with power saving as in, if so can someone explain how it works?

Thanks

Comment: Please link the receiver's pdf data sheet into your question.

Comment: Other than power-saving/waking up, it is nice to hook up such pins to a LED for troubleshooting purposes. Like if you suspect you are getting jammed - power off the intended transmitter and look at the LED on the receiver. If there's still energy at the supposed carrier frequency, then some other device is sending.

Answer (score 1):

In general terms, CD (carrier detect) indicates that a signal is present in a radio band or channel of interest. This allows a receiver to "sleep" in an inactive low power mode in the absence  of signal, and to be "woken up" when CD goes true.

A 1 mS wakeup time would be an acceptable transmit preamble delay in many applications, and the -107 dBm sensitivity is better than the minimum signal level required by most utility data receivers. This ensures that the receiver will be woken up on even the weakest viable signal, or even strong noise bursts. The CD system would need to operate on "in band signal" that was relevant to the receiver - otherwise it would be activated on irrelevant signals.

Web search [receiver sensitivity dbm](https://www.google.com/search?q=receiver+sensitivity+dbm&sca_esv=601666692&sxsrf=ACQVn0-QC291xw_zVtzZqPEikcHeSVCz6Q%3A1706253290062&ei=6luzZbq4A8Xr1e8PrL6y-A0&ved=0ahUKEwi61YDqwPqDAxXFdfUHHSyfDN8Q4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=receiver+sensitivity+dbm&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiGHJlY2VpdmVyIHNlbnNpdGl2aXR5IGRibTIFEAAYgAQyBhAAGBYYHjIGEAAYFhgeMgYQABgWGB4yBhAAGBYYHjIGEAAYFhgeMgYQABgWGB4yBhAAGBYYHjILEAAYgAQYigUYhgNIuIEBUJMQWMh-cAZ4AJABAJgBpQKgAe8pqgEGMC4xOS44uAEDyAEA-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-QEYlwUYjAUY3QQYRhj0Axj1Axj2A9gBAcICCBAAGBYYHhgPwgIGEAAYHhgNwgIIEAAYBRgeGA3CAggQABgIGB4YDeIDBBgBIEGIBgG6BgYIARABGBM&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)

In power down mode the current may be well under 1 mA (and maybe in the 10's of uA range), while receive current will typically be in the 5-20 mA range and may be much more.
If time when an active receive signal is present are a small percentage of total time then very substantial power savings can be achieved.

The [RX2-433-160-3V](https://rfmodules.com.au/RX2-433-160-3V) description says that receive current is up to 13 mA. This is trivial in mains powered equipment but cold be extremely significant for portable or off grid use.

[Full datasheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/da50/0900766b8002fb03.pdf)

13 mA x 3v3 x 24 hours a day =~ 1 Wh.
That's 10% of the capacity of a typical 18650 LiIon cell, or 33% of a small prismatic 1000 mAh cell. And would need a 1 Watt plus PV panel to safely power it in winter months in many locations on earth.

---

**CD Use:**

In the case of the RX2 the CD pin appears to be an output that indicates that the unit is receiving inband signal, but not necessarily data.
Fig3 on page 3 of the datasheet shows CD connection as an output.

In some systems a CD signal could be used similarly but allow portions of the receiver proper to be powered up by the user. In this case the actual RX2 module does not have this capability.

Comment: McMahon Thanks so much for the response. I understand the purpose of CD now. Just wanted to clarify one thing. The power saving stuff is already built into the receiver chip based on the value of CD and CD is just an "indication pin" for the user telling them that data is on the carrier? Or do we have to built extra circuitry based on CD's value to make sure the chip goes into power saving mode and so on .....

Comment: @Vagabond4761 see addition at end of answer. It's just an output in this case. || I have cited the datasheet - when asking questions it is usually helpful to provide links to cited material when available.